# Tension in a rod rotating about a fixed point

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotation, rotational-kinematics, centripetal-force

A rod of mass $m$ and length $l$ is rising about a fixed point in the ceiling with an angular velocity $\omega$ as shown in the figure. [image: figure]

Now, on taking a small element on the rod, the net tension force will act along the rod upwards. Taking components of tension $T$ along vertical and horizontal:
$$T = \delta{m}g\cos{\theta} $$
Therefore, as tension is providing centripetal force,
$$T\sin{\theta} = \delta{m}\omega^2r $$ where $r =$ radius of the circle in which the element is rotating.

Implies:
$$ \omega^2r = g \tan{\theta} $$

[image: figure]
Now here's the problem, everything except $r$ is a constant, I.e $r$ depends on the element we take. How is that possible ?

Comment: From my presumption r is merely depending on the speed of rotation vis a vis the angle with the vertical

Comment: Here r is radius of any circle in which an element of rotating. For same values of $\theta $ and $\omega$, r should take different values.